# Getting 405 when posting to php file

Tags: nginx, http-post, http-status-code-405

I have an html form which posts to to `mysite.com/s/form.php`, but when I submit the form I the error `405 Not Allowed`. Could this be a permissions issue? Or is it something else? I'm stuck at this point.

This is my current config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/mysite.com/site/;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location /s/ {
    alias /var/www/mysite.com/s/;
  }
}
```

Could someone please point out what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the bit that makes php work, so nginx thought it was the POST was being sent to a static file, which nginx does not allow.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you did?